# How to setup basic-auth in express-gateway?

Tags: express-gateway

I'm trying to setup express-gateway with basic-auth and I can't figure out how to use it.

The [docs](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/policies/basic-authorization/) state that

> In order to use the Basic Authorization policy, consumers must be
> created and basic-auth credentials created for them.
>
> To create consumers (users and apps): use the CLI and create user or
> create app command.
>
> To create a basic-auth credential for an app or user: use the CLI and
> create credential command with type basic-auth.

And this works fine, but how should I setup in my application?

I want users to be created automatically when they register into my app, not via CLI. Should I receive the request from the user and make a request to the express-gateway admin?

I'm clearly missing something pretty obvious, but I can't quite get it.

Comment: My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70567538) might be tangentially relevant.